# Show that $PS$ is the smallest ideal of $S$ that contains $h(P)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

**Let $h: R\to S$ be a ring homomorphism. Let $P\subset R$ be a prime ideal.
Denote by $PS$ to the set $$PS=\{s\in S: s=\sum_{i \text{ finite}}h(r_i)s_i, r_i\in R, s_i\in S\}$$**

**Show that $PS$ is the smallest ideal of $S$ that contains $h(P)$.**

I have to prove that $PS=\bigcap_{J\subset S \text{ ideal}, h(P)\subset J}J$ but I do not know how to do this, could someone help me please? Thank you very much.

Comment: Take an arbitrary ideal containing $h(P)$. Now use properties of ideals to show it contains sums and products by $S$

Comment: Are you sue you don't want $\sum h(r_i)s_i$ with $r_i \in P$ instead of $r_i \in R$  Otherwise I can't see how $P$ enters into the question. Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis I found the problem like that but I also think the same so that everything makes sense! In the case where $r_i\in R$ would also be true?

Comment: Well, maybe it makes sense; I mean, it looks like $PS$ will contain $h(P)$ since it contains $h(R)$, at least if $S$ has a unit.  I'll try to think about it if I get any (dearly bought) spare time.  Cheers!

Comment: By the way, ***do*** $R$ and/or $S$ have units?

Comment: @RobertLewis    $R$ and $S$ are commutative rings with unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand\Z{\mathbb Z}$It can't be true. As Robert Lewis pointed out in the comments the right hand side is not related to $P$ at all.

Here is an easy counterexample take $R=S=\Z$ and $h$ to be the identity map and $P$ to be the ideal $2\Z$. In this case $PS=\Z$ but the smallest ideal containing $2\Z=h(2\Z)$ is $2\Z$.